# Django from github to PC without requirements.txt

Tags: django, requirements.txt

wanted to ask if it is possible and if it worth to try to run a cloned Django repo which doesn't have a requirements.txt file

ThankYou!

Comment: hard to say without more info. maybe there's a `Pipfile`, or poetry `toml`, or readme, etc.

Comment: If there is no dependency config file at all you will have to just try to run the project and install each dependency when you get an import error for it. Updating the requirements file every time you install a package is probably a good idea